# Wagtail API v2.4 - How do I show/get the root URL for an image within the API

Tags: wagtail

I'm new to wagtail and I'm creating a site with react.js as the frontend and wagtail as the backend. I'm primarily using wagtail's API and axios to render content to react. That said, I'm having issues getting the full absolute URL from wagtail's API to render images. For example, the get response when making a call for the URL is  "/media/images/ayoba-desk.2e16d0ba.fill-1500x1500.png". How do I get the absolute URL (i.e. 127.0.0.1:8000/../../)?

Model.py

```
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from django.db.models import TextField
from rest_framework import serializers
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, MultiFieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.images.api.fields import ImageRenditionField

from wagtail.search import index
from wagtail.api import APIField


class ProjectsPage(Page):
# db fields
project_h_one = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="Project Name")
project_h_two = models.CharField(
    max_length=250, default="Project Description")
project_intro_p = models.TextField(blank=True)
project_h2_date = models.CharField(
    max_length=250, default="Project Launch Date")
project_p = models.TextField(blank=True)
project_h2_tech_stack = models.CharField(
    max_length=250, default="Tech Stack")
project_tech_stack_description = RichTextField(blank=True, features=["ul"])
project_image = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='+'
)

# Search index configuration
search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
    index.SearchField('project_h_one'),
    index.FilterField('project_h_two'),
    index.FilterField('project_intro_p'),
    index.FilterField('project_h2_date'),
    index.FilterField('project_p'),
    index.FilterField('project_h2_tech_stack'),
    index.FilterField('project_tech_stack_description'),
]

# Editor panels configuration
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('project_h_one'),
    FieldPanel('project_h_two', classname="full"),
    FieldPanel('project_intro_p', classname="full"),
    FieldPanel('project_h2_date', classname="full"),
    FieldPanel('project_p', classname="full"),
    FieldPanel('project_h2_tech_stack', classname="full"),
    FieldPanel('project_tech_stack_description', classname="full"),
    ImageChooserPanel('project_image'),
]
promote_panels = [
    MultiFieldPanel(Page.promote_panels, "Common page configuration"),
]

# API configuration
api_fields = [
    APIField('project_h_one'),
    APIField('project_h_two'),
    APIField('project_intro_p'),
    APIField('project_h2_date'),
    APIField('project_p'),
    APIField('project_h2_tech_stack'),
    APIField('project_tech_stack_description'),
    APIField('project_image'),
    APIField('project_img', serializer=ImageRenditionField(
        'fill-1500x1500', source='project_image')),

]
```

Comment: After reviewing and slacking some wagtail devs I was able to solve this is issue. Essentially, since this still on my local, I needed to change my url patterns within my urls.py file to "urlpatterns += static('/media/images/',
                          document_root=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images')) ". I also had to change my dev.py media_url to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'. Once I did that, I was able to render images within my React.js frontend from the API via axios.